# fork and existing threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, fork

On a linux system, does the child process view the existing threads the same way as the parent process ?

```
int main() {

  //create thread 1

  int child_pid = fork();

  if ( 0 == child_pid)
  {
       ..
  }
  else
  {
       ..
  }
```

Since the whole address space is copied for the child process, what happens to the state of the threads. What if the thread 1 in the above segment is waiting on a conditional signal. Is it in the waiting state in child process as well ?

Answer (score 23):

Threads on Linux nowadays try to stay POSIX compliant. Only the calling thread is replicated, not other threads (note that e.g. on Solaris you can choose what fork does depending on what library you link to)

From http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fork.html (POSIX 2004):

> A process shall be created with a
>   single thread. If a multi-threaded
>   process calls `fork()`, the new process
>   shall contain a replica of the calling
>   thread and its entire address space,
>   possibly including the states of
>   mutexes and other resources.
>   Consequently, to avoid errors, the
>   child process may only execute
>   async-signal-safe operations until
>   such time as one of the `exec` functions
>   is called.  Fork
>   handlers may be established by means
>   of the `pthread_atfork()` function in
>   order to maintain application
>   invariants across `fork()` calls.

The POSIX 2018 specification of [`fork()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) is similar.

Comment: Thanks. The link is of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are not inherited from a child process on a linux system using fork().  An in-depth source is here: http://linas.org/linux/threads-faq.html

Comment: That FAQ is very out of date.  The largest user-visible difference is that LinuxThreads has been obsoleted by NPTL ever since kernel 2.6 and glibc 2.3, which resolves all outstanding issues with non-POSIX-like threading behavior.