# fork() duplicates process, how about threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, fork

I am figuring out how threads with fork work and here is the code that I have tried to make some sense of. (Pardon the errors in the code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
void* f(int threadnum) {
    int i;
    i = fork();

    if (i == 0) {   // child process
        printf("(%d) child says hello\n", threadnum);
    } else {
        printf("(%d) parent[%d] says hello\n", threadnum, i);
        wait(NULL);
        int new = fork();
        if (new != 0){
            printf("(%d) parent[%d] says hello to grandchild\n", threadnum, new);
            wait(NULL);
        } else 
            printf("(%d) grandchild says hello\n", threadnum);
    }
}

 int main () 
{
    pthread_t pid[2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        pthread_create(&pid[i], NULL, f, (void *)i);
        printf("Thread created with id [%li]\n", pid[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        pthread_join(pid[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output that i have gotten:

```
Thread created with id [663664384]
Thread created with id [655271680]
(1) parent[5690] says hello
(0) parent[5691] says hello
(1) child says hello
(1) parent[5692] says hello to grandchild
(0) child says hello
(1) grandchild says hello
(0) parent[5693] says hello to grandchild
(0) grandchild says hello
```

I don't see much difference as to how threads work differently from having to fork the calling of f() twice. 
If a single thread executes exit(), how about the whole process?
If a single thread calls exec(), how about the other threads?

Comment: Related to (possibly a duplicate of) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056903/multithreaded-fork

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour by not returning a valid value from the thread function.  Ensure you have `return 0;` on every exit path from the thread function (unless you have a useful value to return).

Comment: Note that the 'grandchild' process is actually a second sibling to the first forked process; it has the same parent process.

Comment: If your program used mutexes, for example, and the sole thread in a forked process needed to use a mutex locked by a different thread in the pre-forked process, then the process is deadlocked — there is no way to release that locked mutex.  This is one of the many reasons you have to be careful.  Your code isn't using mutexes; that makes it simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You will not see much difference in the behavior with your current code. A major difference between a thread and a process is in the memory layout.

A child thread uses the same virtual memory as the parent, whereas a child process has it's own copy of VM. Hence you can see the difference in the behavior of thread and fork by calling `exit()` from various places in your code.

If you call `exit()` from the place where *parent says hello* (Essentially, from the new thread)process will exit immediately since it's using the same VM. Whereas if the `exit()` is called from *child says hello* (Meaning from the new process), rest of the print statements will continue, since the child has it's own memory space.